# trying to update PostGIS the_geom column with new, simplified the_geom?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with multipolygon the_geom field. Some of the multipolygons were very detailed, and queries ran slowly, so I simplified the_geom with st_simplify_preserve_topology.  That part was successful, but now I'm trying to replace the old the_geom field with the new one, but the query hangs longer than I would think.

Here's what I ran first, and it ran quickly, in about 60 seconds.

```
SELECT ST_Multi(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(the_geom,0.005)) as fwz_simple FROM fwz;
```

Then when I try to update the table, it runs and never finishes, after about 30 minutes of waiting.

```
UPDATE fwz SET the_geom = subquery.the_geom FROM (SELECT ST_Multi(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(the_geom,0.005)) as fwz_simple FROM fwz) as subquery;
```

Will the query know where to put the geometries within the context of the whole tables?  In other words, how does the UPDATE statement know which name, etc field to align the geometries with?  Is that what's causing the delay?

Thank you for any help. I can of course provide more detail if that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

For each row in your table, you are updating the geometry with every simplified geometry from the subquery. At the end, all geometries will be the same (the last one from the subquery).

You can skip the entire subquery and work on each row geometry directly:

```
UPDATE fwz 
SET the_geom = ST_Multi(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(the_geom,0.005));
```